# How to find the shortest path cover a specific set of edges in a weighted undirected graph?

Tags: algorithm, search, graph, artificial-intelligence, a-star

Given a weighted undirected graph(say with nodes A,B,C,D,E), and a set of jobs which require to go from one node to another(say A->C,A-B,D->E,E->F). How to find the shortest path starting from A which covers all jobs in the job set?

P.S. Triangle inequality applies, which means if there exists an edge from x to y then it is the shortest path from x to y.

Do not need to go back to A.

Jobs are directed.

Hinted to use A star algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on something similar. This algorithm might be helpful www.geeksforgeeks.org/travelling-salesman-problem-set-1/